# How can I get a 4k image of webpage render without a 4k monitor?

Tags: image, pdf, browser, rendering, resolution

We've all been there - a webpage formats correctly and looks great, but when we print it or html2pdf it breaks all the formatting. You can take a screenshot but the DPI (~70) is far too low for print where you need ~300 DPI.

So, is there a tool or a way to trick your computer/browser into rendering a page at a much higher resolution, like 3840x2160, and then saving that render to later be printed? The end goal here is a PDF (with 300 DPI) or image (4k res).